# Program to print sum of natural number between 1 to 7 in python​ for loop​

Tags: python

**I want to print the sum of 7 natural numbers for my school project can you help me**

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! [How to ask homework question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) and [Open letter to students with homework problems](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems)

Comment: Python has a built-in function `sum()`. And it has a function `range()` to return a sequence of numbers. You should be able to combine these to do what you want.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

```
sum=0

for i in range(1,8):

          sum+=i

print("Sum of the natural no.s from 1 to 7 is:",sum)
```

## it will help you for your project

Comment: Don't do their homework for them, please.